# What is the value of $1\%0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let $x$ be an integer which can take a value of $0$ or $1$. The statement

if $(x = = 0) x = 1;$
 else $x = 0;$

is equivalent to which one of the following ?

1. $x = 1 + x;$
2. $x  = 1 - x;$
3. $x = x - 1;$
4. $x = 1\% x;$

---

My attempt :

It should be only option $(2)$ is true. but,

> Can you explain little bit please, what is the value of $1\%0$ ?

AFAIK: It should be undefined, since it applied division $1/0$ which is undefined.

Comment: This sounds more like a programming question than a mathematics one. I suspect as code it would throw a run time error if you tried to do mod zero.

Comment: Mathematicians tend not to use % as an operator, and we tend not to assign variables new values. This is a coding problem? The best definition would be that $a%0==a$ for all $a$, but who knows what it would be in the language at hand - depends precisely on the definition.

Comment: You can find your answer over here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516251/why-is-n-mod-0-undefined

Comment: If you are talking about the C programming language, then the behaviour of  `1%0` is **undefined**, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370154/cant-mod-zero. That might be different for other programming languages.

Comment: Mathematicians typically use **=** for equations, and indicate the assignment of a new  value as **:=** or a leftward pointing $\mapsto$ (not sure what the symbol for this is). In your case, since $x$ is boolean, the assignment can be written as $x := NOT x$ or $x := 1-x$, since the assignment inverts TRUE and FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$1\%0$" would be equivalent to $1-\Big\lfloor\frac10\Big\rfloor\times0$.

Modulo by $0$ is as meaningless as Division by $0$.

Comment: Is $\%$ operator dependents on division operator?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: Depends on what context (purely mathematical, C language standard, Python, CPU architecture, etc). Anyone can choose to "implement" it in anyway that they want, i.e., no one's "telling" how to do it, just as long as you do it correctly.

Comment: Is $x = x\% 1$ is equivalent to $x = 1 - x$ ?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: $\forall{n\in\mathbb{Z}}:n\%1=0$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for explanation.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: You're welcome.